# Dart MD5 From String

Tags: dart

How to generate md5 hash from string?

```
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart' as crypto;
///Generate MD5 hash
generateMd5(String data) {
  var content = UTF8.encode(data);
  var md5 = crypto.md5;
}
```

I have no idea what next to do

Answer (score 116, accepted):

A more efficient approach would be the following:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';

String generateMd5(String input) {
  return md5.convert(utf8.encode(input)).toString();
}
```

This avoids loading the unnecessary `convert` package and uses the already existing `Utf8Codec`, instead of instantiating a `Utf8Encoder` object each time the function is called.

Comment: If anyone does not have the [crypto package](https://pub.dev/packages/crypto) installed yet, install it using `flutter pub add crypto`.

Answer (score 24):

Found an answer:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:convert/convert.dart';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart' as crypto;

///Generate MD5 hash
generateMd5(String data) {
  var content = new Utf8Encoder().convert(data);
  var md5 = crypto.md5;
  var digest = md5.convert(content);
  return hex.encode(digest.bytes);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Just to save anyone else a few minutes of searching, to hash/digest a file from a stream you can use:

```dart
    final fileStream = File('path/to/file.txt').openRead();
    final checksum = (await md5.bind(fileStream).first).toString();
```